# Javascript Input Value Not Changeable By User

Tags: javascript, submit, validation, dom-manipulation

I am relatively new to Javascript and having some trouble with changing values.

Here is my Javascript:

```
function printResults(results, numMeals){
    calories=Math.round(results);
    protein= Math.round(results/4*.4);
    carbs=Math.round(results/4*.3);
    fats=Math.round(results/9*.3);
    document.getElementById("calories").innerHTML="Total Calories: " + ('<input type="text" id= "totalCal">');
    document.getElementById("totalCal").value=calories;
    document.getElementById("protein").innerHTML="Grams of Protein: " + ('<input type="text" id="totalProtein">');  
    document.getElementById("totalProtein").value=protein;  
    document.getElementById("carbs").innerHTML="Grams of Carbs: " + ('<input type="text" id="totalCarbs">'); 
    document.getElementById("totalCarbs").value=carbs;  
    document.getElementById("fats").innerHTML="Grams of Fat: " + ('<input type="text" id="totalFats">'); 
    document.getElementById("totalFats").value=fats;
    calories= Number(document.getElementById("totalCal").value);
    protein= Number(document.getElementById("totalProtein").value);
    carbs= Number(document.getElementById("totalCarbs").value);
    fats= Number(document.getElementById("totalFats").value);
    document.getElementById("search").innerHTML= ('<a class="btn" href="search/'+calories+'/'+protein+'/'+carbs+'/'+fats+'/'+numMeals+'">Find Meals</a><br>');}
```

And it edits these html input fields:

```
    <div class="span2" style="text-align:left">
    <span id="calories"> Total Calories: -</span><br>
    <span id="protein"> Protein: -</span><br>
    <span id="carbs"> Carbs: -</span><br>
    <span id="fats"> Fats: -</span><br>
    <span id="search"></span><br>
    </div>
```

This works with setting the initial values, however, when I edit the value of the text field manually, it does not change the value upon submission.  For example if the original calories are set to 2000 based on the calculations and then I edit the text field to 2500, my search still yields a value of 2000.

Comment: As I read your js, the last row of your function sets a link `Find meals` with the initial search values? Then of course the link won't return the values if changed after?

Comment: Your values in the search innerHTML all depend on the results variable in the printResults function. How do you call that function? You need to call it using your text fields values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, instead of changing `innerHtml` of `#search`, change it to `<a>` or `<button>`, handle `click` event and get the values in the event. Otherwise you are generating search link earlier than the value is changed, so it includes old values.

Also there is no reason to generate inputs dynamically, define them in html and only change the `value` as required.

As a side note, I really recommend looking into jQuery as it makes these things much less verbose.